# Relationship between linar and multilinear maps?

Tags: differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra

Given a linear map $l: V^k \rightarrow F$, is there some way to construct a multilinear map that somehow corresponds to this?

Similarly, given a multilinear map $m: V^k \rightarrow F$, is there some linear map that corresponds to this?

I'm trying to build an intuition for "regular" linearity and multilinearity. Any views on how to understand these operations and their relationships would be great.

How do I intuitively think of a multilinear map? Isn't the multi-linearlity property "weird", in that we need **all the other coordinates fixed**? How do I think about this?

Comment: I think this is one of the motivations for tensor product. Are familiar with this? If not, look at the Wiki page. Specifically, the *universal property* is what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't require $m$ to be both linear and multilinear.

Pick $v\in V^k$ such that $m(v) = a\ne 0$. Then by linearity we have $m(2v)=2a$ yet by multilinearity we have also $m(2v)=2^ka$.

Multilinearity just means being linear in every component. A very elementary example is the inner product on $\Bbb R^n$ (which is *bi*-linear), and another common multilinearity map is the $\det$ map from $(\Bbb F^n)^n$ to $\Bbb F$.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. The question was asking something slightly different: is there *any* linear map that corresponds to the $m$ shown? However, this is also enlightening in its own right :)

Comment: @SiddharthBhat "corresponds" is a vague term (unless you're talking in a context that I am unfamiliar with where "corresponds" is actually given special meaning). Anyway would you care to make it more specific?

Comment: I'm actually unsure what sort of correspondence I was looking for, hence I kept it vague :) Roughly, is it possible to identify every multilinear map with *some* linear map? What about vice versa?



As an analogy, given a galois correspondence, we can identify subfields with subgroups. Is there some  construction possible like that between multi-linear and linear maps?